# Div Table Layout - Cells same height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm doing layout in Bootstrap, my css is as following (background-color set for debugging):

```
<div class="row" style="display: table; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: red;">
    <div class="col-md-8" style="display: table-cell; height: 100%; background-color: blue;">
        <textarea id="events-text" class="form-control" style="height: 100%;"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="display: table-cell;">
        <div class="btn-group-vertical" style="width: 100%;">
            {% for category in categories %}
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs category-select">
               {{ category.name }}
            </button>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the effect is:

[image]

I want textarea go same height as buttons on the right. The problem is that it's table cell doesn't go full height so neither go textarea. How can I make this table-cell go same height as the on on the right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the floats on the `table-cell` (float:left is being added by Bootstrap)..

http://www.bootply.com/116934